# pull rendered cell data from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm hoping there is a way to pull the rendered cell data from a table

I am using angularjs with angular-datatables and it renders the table fine however I'd like to pull that rendered data into a different service but I can't find in the datatables api where to get that rendered cell data

for example I use a .withRender on each column which looks at the date field and formats it

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('due_date').withTitle('Due Date')
          .renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
            if (full.due_date) {
              return moment(full.due_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
            return '-';
          }),
```

I'd like to be able to access those conditional changes and have that as the data rather than the initial ajax data (e.g. the date or the '-')

I have this working fine for column headers (I made a map to map rendered headers to a field

```
function generateColumnMap(dt) {
        var columnMap = {};
        dt.columns().every(function () {

          if (!this.visible()) {
            return;
          }

          var header = this.header().innerText
          var field = this.dataSrc()


          if (field) {
            columnMap[field] = header
          }
        })
        return columnMap
      }
```

is there something similar to get the rendered cells from each row and replace the ajax data with that conditional text via the datatable api?

Comment: Edit: is there a reason you must use datatable api to do this? If you want to replace the data, why don't you transform it in your data service one time and use one transformed version everywhere?

Comment: It's complicated, I'd have to sit you down on a campfire and discuss with you the ghost story of legacy code that I have taken over.. I really don't have a choice not to use it until the team wants to refactor it.

Comment: `var data = table.cells( idx, '' ).render( 'display' ); console.log( data );`

Answer (score 0):

I used the suggestion below to get what I needed.

```js
var data = table.cells( idx, '' ).render( 'display' ); console.log( data );
```